# sencha touch ListPaging plugin "load more" button position issue

Tags: javascript, list, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm facing an issue regarding the position of the **Load More...** button in `sencha touch2`. Here, the Load More button is added using **ListPaging** plugin and from the `Ext.plugins.Listpaging` docs it states:

> Adds a Load More button at the **bottom** of the list. When the user
>   presses this button, the next page of data will be loaded into the
>   store and appended to the List.

But, here, the list item with load more button appears at the top of the list, not to the bottom.
See my code here:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyLIst', {
            extend : 'Ext.dataview.List',
            xtype : 'mylist',
            id : 'myList' ,
            requires : [Ext.data.Store','Ext.plugin.ListPaging'],

            config : {
                width : '100%',
                height : '100%',
                loadingText : 'Loading data...',
                emptyText : 'No Members',
                itemTpl : '<div class="mylisttitle">{title}</div>',
                store : 'mylistStore',
                plugins : [
                        {
                        xclass : 'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
                        autoPaging : false,
                        loadNextPage: function() {
                                console.log('Load more button clicked');
                            // fire event here
                            }
                        }],
                masked : false,
                mode : 'SINGLE',
                scrollable : {
                    direction : 'vertical',
                    directionLock : true
                }
            }

        });
```

and see the result below:
[image]

Any idea how could I show the same button at the bottom of the list?

Thanks

**EDIT**: I had posted the issue in senchatouch forum to, still awaiting a solution, you can see it [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?264629-Load-more-button-appears-at-the-top-of-List-while-using-ListPaging-plugin)

Comment: If you have any custom css try disabling it. Or if you are able to reproduce the same issue in a fiddle it would be more easier to fix. Here is a work demo http://jsfiddle.net/blessenm/9ypwk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved it:**

I was missing this :  **`infinite: true`**

Load more button now appears at the bottom .

Thanks  @blessenm for the [working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/blessenm/9ypwk/) :-)

Answer (score 2):

Kind of strange. Can you try removing these properties (width, height and scrollable) and adding "layout:fit" to the parent of this list.

Comment: Wel, that was the very first thing I tried after posting this question..stil makes no change :-(

Answer (score 1):

If you have any custom css try disabling it. Or if you are able to reproduce the same issue in a fiddle it would be more easier to fix. Here is a work demo jsfiddle.net/blessenm/9ypwk

```
Ext.application({
    launch: function () {
        Ext.define('TweetStore', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

            config: {


         fields: ['from_user', 'profile_image_url', 'text', 'created_at'],

            pageSize: 25,
            autoLoad: true,

            proxy: {
                type: 'jsonp',
                url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json',

                pageParam: 'page',
                limitParam: 'rpp',

                extraParams: {
                    q: 'sencha'
                },

                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'results'
                }
            }
        }
    });

    Ext.define('MyApp.list.List', {
        extend: 'Ext.List',

        config: {
            useSimpleItems: false,
            variableHeights: true,
            infinite: true,
            disableSelection: true,
            allowDeselect: false,
            store: Ext.create('TweetStore'),
            loadingText: 'Loading data...',
            emptyText: 'No Members',

            plugins: [{
                xclass: 'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
                autoPaging: false
            }],

            itemTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                '<div>{text}</div>'),
            masked: false,
            mode: 'SINGLE',
            scrollable: {
                direction: 'vertical',
                directionLock: true
            }
        }
    });

    Ext.define('MyApp.list.Container', {
        extend: 'Ext.Container',
        config: {
            fullscreen: true,
            layout: 'vbox',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'Load More Plugin',
            }, {
                xclass: 'MyApp.list.List',
                flex: 1
            }]
        }
    });
    Ext.create('MyApp.list.Container');
}
});
```